# Copy computed css value in chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the example below I would like to copy the value of 'box-shadow'.
But in Chrome Devtools I can't select the value and there is no copy option.
Is there a better way to do this?

I can copy the value in the 'styles' tab, but that contains a bunch of css variables.

[image]

**Update:** a extra nice option would be 'Copy computed styles' here:
[image]

Comment: Yes AFAIK, there is no direct option to do this from the "Computed" tab. You have already found the second best way to do it. Probably something that can be raised as a feature request.

Comment: Raised a ticket here for Edge atleast, https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools/issues/104

Comment: Really finding trying to get resultant css vars to be a pain in computed panel. Hopefully we get copy ability soon.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by hovering over a word in the RHS of some value, where the I beam cross-section shape pointer shows up. Double click to get it to select the word. Then hit Ctrl + A, Ctrl + C. See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]